# How can I remove extra last semicolon in csv file?

Tags: php

How can I remove extra last semicolon in csv file. Because it's taking extra blank field.

Below is format of csv file.

12/12/2010;vvvvvv;JJJJ;BB;02070;kkkk yyyy tt oooo ;jjj iii;;mm nn nnnn;nnnnn gg bbbbb;xxxx ccc;;63610 iiiiiii;http://google.com;aaa bbb;;06 85 83 38 25;;aaa@vv.com;;2010-12-12;T;nnn;bbb-rr;rrr;rrr;3 C;N;

Comment: Pedantic note: That's not a csv file.  It's either a delimited text file, or a ssv (semicolon separated value) file...

Comment: I hope you edited that CSV to remove any private details before you posted it?

Comment: thank you.next time i will take care of that.

Comment: @Rupali - if it is private data, you should edit the question *NOW*.

Comment: Why is having an extra blank field a problem?

Comment: Not like editing it matters much since it's in the history, heh.

Comment: putting *please help me it's urgent!!!!!!!!!* is almost always a sure way to attract downvotes. My general response to those type of questions is: if it's that urgent, hire someone.

Answer (score 1):

After reading you comments I notice you said "remove the last element of an array".

[`array_pop($array);`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_pop.asp) will remove the last element in the array

For a string use:

[rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
$text = '12/12/2010;vvvvvv;JJJJ;BB;02070;kkkk yyyy tt oooo ;jjj iii;;mm nn nnnn;nnnnn gg bbbbb;xxxx ccc;;63610 iiiiiii;http://google.com;aaa bbb;;06 85 83 38 25;;aaa@vv.com;;2010-12-12;T;nnn;bbb-rr;rrr;rrr;3 C;N;';

$trimmed = rtrim($text, ";");

echo $trimmed;
```

Answer (score 0):

How abaout:

```
$str = trim($str, ";");
```

That will remove any semilocons from either the start or the end of the string.
If you only want to remove from the end of the string, use rtrim instead of trim.

Comment: i used this statment for taking csv file data $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $fieldseparator)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
$str = substr($str,0-1);
```

This will remove whatever the last character is, semi-colon or otherwise.

Comment: This is not string.at run time it gives me array with last field blank value.i want remove that last blank field.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were dealing with an array.  Be sure to mention it next time.  I think Phill Pafford's correct with `array_pop`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want to remove the last element from the array after taking the csv file data:

> i used this statment for taking csv file data  $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $fieldseparator)

So, to remove the last element you could try:

```
unset array[count($array)-1];
```